# No Assumptions on Timing - não entendi esse conceito de um livro

Tags: java, multithreading, concorrência, thread-safety

Citado no livro que uma região crítica possui 4 pontos chaves:

> 1. Progresso:

Garante que todas as *threads* estão entrando e saindo da região crítica, evitando *deadlocks*.

> 2. Mutualmente Exclusivo:

Apenas uma *thread* pode estar atuando na região crítica, as demais devem aguardar sua vez.

> 3. Bounded Waiting:

Garante que toda *thread* após um limite de tempo seja permitida dentro da região crítica. Evitando que uma *thread* fiquei muito tempo sem obter progresso por falta de "sorte" na seleção.

> 4. No Assumptions on Timing:

Não fez sentido para mim. O que isso quer dizer?

Além disso, se algum conceito anterior ao quarto estiver incorreto ou incompleto, por favor me corrigir.

Comment: Tem boas perguntas aí, e embora sejam até relacionadas, não são o mesmo problema, editar essa para algo mais focado e manter as outras questões separadas pode ajudar bem e obter boas respostas (vejo pelo menos 3 perguntas distintas, apesar de todoas serem sobre concorrência).

Comment: editado! to tao confuso que nem sei por onde começar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto significa que você não pode considerar quando as coisas vão acontecer. Elas acontecerão quando tiverem que acontecer, na ordem que a aplicação determinar ser melhor e possível no fluxo de processamento atual e levará o tempo que for necessário para concluir a tarefa.

Quando você tem concorrência é comum que o tempo total de execução ou de finalização não seja determinístico (muitos casos podem fazer o tempo não ser determinístico). Você perde um pouco o controle da ordem de execução e quanto tempo de processamento será dedicado a outra tarefa no meio da execução da sua. Durante a execução o seu processamento pode ser interrompido temporariamente (ou indefinidamente se ocorrer um *deadlock*).

O início do seu processamento pode demorar a acontecer por entrar em alguma fila ou porque depende de uma informação que ainda não está disponível. Neste contexto provavelmente o termo indica principalmente estes casos.

Em distribuição complica mais porque você nem sabe quanto tempo a outra máquina demorará para fazer algo, se tem fila, etc.

Comment: ficou claro, obrigado. Com relação aos outros termos, a minha explicação foi coerente?

Comment: Pelo que eu percebi, sim, é claro que não vi  no contexto exato que eles foram usados, mas parece ok.